# Question on Expected Value Integration

Tags: probability, integration

$$
\mathbb{E}[(X - 2)^{+}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(t - 2)^+ f_X(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{14\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(t - 2)^+e^{-(t - 2)^2/14}\,dt
$$

This is how far I have gotten in my homework question, can someone please show me how to do the rest of it, stuck on the '+' symbol in particular but then how do I then integrate it, do I ignore + and just pretend it is (t-2)

Comment: $x^+=\max(x,0)$

Comment: Hint:  break the region of integration in two.  On the first part, $[-\infty,2]$ we have $(t-2)^+=0$.  On the second part, $[2,\infty]$ we have $(t-2)^+=t-2$.

Comment: Split up in $\int_{-\infty}^2+\int_2^{\infty}$

Comment: You should use that $(X - 2)^+$ is the positive part of $(X - 2)$ and $0$, when $(X -2)$ is negative

Comment: Then substitute $s=t-2$ so $\int_{2}^\infty g(t-2) \operatorname d t=\int_0^\infty g(s)\operatorname d s$

Answer (score 1):

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\mathsf E((X-2)^+) ~=~ & \mathsf E(\max(X-2,0))\\[1ex] ~=~ & \mathsf E(X-2\mid X > 2)\mathsf P(X>2)\color{silver}{\cancelto{0}{+\mathsf E(0\mid X\leq 2)\mathsf P(X\leq 2)}} \\[1ex]~=~&\int_2^\infty (t-2)~f_X(t)\operatorname d t\\[1ex] ~=~& \frac{1}{\sqrt{14\pi~}} \int_2^\infty (t-2)\mathsf e^{-(t-2)^2/14}\operatorname d t\\[1ex] ~=~&\frac {\surd 7}{\sqrt{ 2\pi~}}\int_0^\infty s\mathsf e^{-s^2/2}\operatorname d s & s=(t-2)/\surd 7\end{align}$$

That is all.   You can now complete.